# Exponential of symmetrical 4x4 matrix

Tags: matrices, taylor-expansion, exponentiation, transpose

Consider a matrix $A$, such that $A_{ij}=A_{ji}$

I want to find $e^{itA}$

I tried to represent $A$ as sum of 10 different matrices, that would show the symmetry, but the final result ends up to be zero

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: $e^{itA}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(itA)^n\over n!}$

Comment: @Volk that is what I tried already

Comment: Without further context regarding the specific matrix I'm not sure there is much more that can be said...

Comment: For any matrix, Euler tells us that
$$e^{iAt} = \cos(At)+i\,\sin(At)$$ 
Furthermore if $A$ is real and symmetric, then $(iAt)$ is skew-hermitian and $e^{iAt}$ is unitary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, diagonalize your matrix $A$ such that $$A=U^{-1}DU$$

Where $U$ is an orthonormal matrix and $D$ is a diagonal matrix. Now use the following identity:

$$\text{Exp}(itU^{-1}DU)=U^{-1}\text{Exp}(itD)U$$

Notice that $\text{Exp}(D)$ is trivial to compute since $D$ is diagonal.